# Process runtime in kernel space

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to get the runtime of a given process in kernel space or user space.
Anyway here is what i'm trying to do...

```
//suppose struct task_struct *task has a direct link to pid 1
cputime_t ktime = task->cputime_expires.stime;
cputime_t utime = task->cputime_expires.utime;
cputime_t total = ktime + utime;
printk(KERN_INFO "TOTAL [%lu]",total); // 0
```

why the output is zero ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll get process runtime from `task->utime`, `task->stime`, etc.

Check function `account_process_tick()` [source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/cputime.c#L463).

The one you have mentioned i.e `task->cputime_expires` is used for `timer_settime()` system call to arm a POSIX per-process timer.